# how to manage the fragments in android correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've met a lot of different code and each programmer makes its own way. I had a misunderstanding of one thing. it fragments. I met this code:

```
    public static final int FRAGMENT_MAIN_MENU = 1;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_CHOICE = 2;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_CHOICE_TYPE = 3;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_CHOICE_TIME = 4;
................
public void setFragment(int fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

        switch (fragment) {
            case FRAGMENT_MAIN_MENU:
                ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_frame, new MainMenuFragment());
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_CHOICE:
                ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_frame, new ChoiceFragment());
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_CHOICE_TYPE:
                ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_frame, new ChoiceKmFragment());
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_CHOICE_TIME:
                ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_frame, new ChoiceTimeFragment());
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_frame, fragment);

        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

I just met this code:

```
public void pushFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean animate) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        replaceFragment(fragment, animate ? -1 : 0);
    }

    public void pushFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        pushFragment(fragment, true);
    }

public void popFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = fragmentList.get(fragmentList.size() - 2);
    replaceFragment(fragment, 1);
    fragmentList.remove(fragmentList.size() - 1);
}
```

in my application I have done so:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
        Bundle arguments;
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position) {
            case CITY_GUESTS:
                fragment = new GuestsList();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_LINK, getString(R.string.city_guest_link));
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, "city");
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                break;
            case HOLIDAY_GUESTS:
                fragment = new GuestsList();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_LINK, getString(R.string.holiday_guestlist_link));
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, "holiday");
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                break;
            case HOTEL_LOAD_ITEM:
                fragment = new HotelLoadTable();
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Загрузка отелей");
                break;
            case HOTEL_LOAD_ITEM_2:
                fragment = new EstimatedLoad();
                setFragment(fragment,"estimatedLoad");
                setTitle("Загрузка за период");
                break;
            case MONEY_ITEM:
                fragment = new Money();
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Касса");
                break;
            case INFO:
                fragment = new StatusInfo();
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Статус инфо");
                break;
            case EMPLOYEE_ITEM:
                fragment = new EmployeessList();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_LINK, getString(R.string.employee_list_link));
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                break;
            case CITY_CONF:
                fragment = new PagerCalendarContainer();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, "city");
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Конференции City");
                break;
            case HOLIDAY_CONF:
                fragment = new PagerCalendarContainer();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, "holiday");
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Конференции Holiday");
                break;
            case CITY_SURVEY:
                fragment = new SurveyGuestsList();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, "city");
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("City survey");
                break;
            case HOLIDAY_SURVEY:
                fragment = new SurveyGuestsList();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, "holiday");
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Holiday survey");
                break;
            case CITY_LOGBUK:
                fragment = new PagerLogbookContainer();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, "city");
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Логбук City");
                break;
            case HOLIDAY_LOGBUK:
                fragment = new PagerLogbookContainer();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, "holiday");
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Логбук Holiday");
                break;
            case CALL:
                fragment = new CallRequest();
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Запросить звонок");
                break;
            case LOGOUT:
                fragment = new LogOut();
                arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_LOGIN, global_login);
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                setFragment(fragment);
                setTitle("Logout");
                break;
        }

    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        fManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        fManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment,String tag) {
        fManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        fManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment,tag).commit();
    }
```

how to work with fragments? there can be any pattern or way to do this easily? to avoid problems and difficulties? where Google shows how to do it? if I have a lot of pieces, and I have to install and uninstall them, they have different settings, and so on. and may have a special library? Please share the information!

Comment: "How to work with fragments" is too broad. What is your exact question?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: is there any way to install / uninstall fragments, which has the least code and easy to use? Is there an official example of what I brought in my question?

Comment: I want to know that the most correct of my three examples, or is there another example that does the same thing but more correctly

Comment: in other words, is it possible to improve my third example, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are all valid approaches (basically using the Android transactions to replace fragments). You are encapsulating the common actions into methods, which is always good OO.

Google shows a similar article here called 'building flexible ui's:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

As for general patterns when using fragments, I try to think of a fragment as a 'section of a screens ui' that may be reused and or can be logically grouped.

When deciding how you organise your fragments when associating activities, there are two that I know of (I have attended many presentations at Droidcon and these are always described):

1. Create a FragmentActivity for each logical screen in the UI, then make it manage the one or more fragments that are using on that screen.
2. Create one single activity for the entire app which then manages every fragment.

Both are valid, but I usually go with option 1, creating a activity per UI screen and then having that activity manage the fragments used on that screen. It grows better and seems more OO to me.

I only rarely use option 2 if the app is very very compact and small (not many ui screens). As it gets messy fast.

Then as more UI screens are created, I create another activity for it, finally adding that screens fragments.

Although you didn't specifically ask about communication between fragments, I also find that my code is a lot easier to maintain by using one of the Android Event Bus libraries ([Green robot event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is my favourite ,but I hear good things about 'otto' too).

By using an event bus, you can easily communicate between fragments/screens by firing an event.

Comment: it's a great answer. exactly what I was interested! By the way about Otto I've heard and I'm going to try it. you said something that interested me, despite my bad english)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Plus Good luck with the otto library. I use a event bus pattern in all my apps now.